# Ручное присвоение ID объекту

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу создать объект и присвоить ему ID вручную. Например `Model.create(id: 100, title: 'Object 100')`

Как сделать чтобы при создании следующего объекта Model.create(title: 'Object 101'), его ID был соответственно 101, а не 1 как делает рейлс?

Answer (score 2):

[Вот тут пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075331/change-starting-id-number), что нужно установить счетчик автоинкремента для поля таблицы. То есть автоинкрементом управляет не Rails, а СУБД.

Для MySQL нужно выполнить:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100")
```

Для Postgres:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq START with 100 RESTART;")
```

Нужно сгенерировать миграцию, поместить туда вышеприведенный код, заменив `table_name` на имя таблицы, запустить миграцию.